# Android parsing string to url to InetAddress results in a error

Tags: android, string, parsing, url

I am trying to get the host and IP address from a URL. This URL is given by a text field, when the button is clicked a want the given text to be stored in a string, and I want to convert that string to a URL. This is my code:

```
String value;
String ip;
URL url;

public void btnOnClick(View v){


    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
    value = "http://" + text.getText().toString();
    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewOutput);

    if (value.length() < 3){
        output.setText("At least 3 characters are required ");
    }else{
        try {
            url = new URL(value);

            //Here is where I get my error: (look below for the given error) 
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(***url***).getHost());

            ip = address.getHostAddress();

        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The error:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/b6vpxy.jpg

So it seems to me that it doesn't convert the string to a URL, and I don't know how I can fix this. If someone could point me in the right direction and tell me what I do wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your image link doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: http://oi60.tinypic.com/b6vpxy.jpg

Comment: It works for me I don't understand why it does not for you.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `url` is already of type `URL`. no need to do `new URL(url)`, just do this instead:

```
       InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost());
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error: UnknownHostException

Comment: That means that the host name was not found. Does it work for a well known host name such as 'stackoverflow.com'?

Comment: Doing this:                 url = new URL("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(url.getHost()); gives the same error  (the http and the www. part is removed automatically by stack but its there)

Comment: You have to set the protocol. Try with http:// www.stackoverflow.com and it will work.

Comment: This works just fine for me with 'http:// stackoverflow.com' (minus the space) if the device has a proper network connection. It fails in airplane mode with UnknownHostException.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to parse url from string:

```
    ArrayList retrieveLinks(String text) {
    ArrayList links = new ArrayList();

    String regex = "\\(?\\b(http://|www[.])[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while(m.find()) {
    String urlStr = m.group();
    char[] stringArray1 = urlStr.toCharArray();

    if (urlStr.startsWith("(") && urlStr.endsWith(")"))
    {

        char[] stringArray = urlStr.toCharArray(); 

        char[] newArray = new char[stringArray.length-2];
        System.arraycopy(stringArray, 1, newArray, 0, stringArray.length-2);
        urlStr = new String(newArray);
        System.out.println("Finally Url ="+newArray.toString());

    }
    System.out.println("...Url..."+urlStr);
    links.add(urlStr);
    }
    return links;
    }
```

hope this helps.